# How to get tables to line up next to each other

Tags: email, tablelayout

trying to get the shipping details and order details tables to line up next to each other in the same row.  i have them in a wrapper table, and set the widths to 50%, but they still line up in a block format. making one of the widths less than 50% didn't change anything.

----this is an email

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Climatic Corporation</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*RESET STYLES*/
body         {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
img, a img{border:0; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{margin:0; padding:0;}

/*CLIENT SPECIFIC STYLES*/
.ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;}
table,td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
#outlook a{padding:0;}
img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;}

/*Custom Styles*/
#mainTable{
border:4px solid black;
}

/*Mobile Styles*/

@media only screen and (max-width:479px) {
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="620" id="containerTable">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="headerTable">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<img src="CClogo.png" alt="Climatic Corporation Logo">
</td>
<td align="right" valign="top">
<a href="tel:800-845-4555">800-845-4555</a>
<br>
<a href="mailto:csr@climaticcorp.com">csr@climaticcorp.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.climatichomeproducts.com">climatichomeproducts.com</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="mainTable">
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="messageTable">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="100%">
<h1>THANK YOU!</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="100%">
<p>Hello @@Shopper - thanks for shopping with us.</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="100%">
<p>Order @@OrderNumber has been placed. We appreciate your business.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="detailsWrapper">
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" id="shippingTable">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<h3>Shipping Details</h3>
<p>@@ShippingAddress</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" id="orderTable">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<h3>Order Details</h3>
<p>@@PONumber</p>
<p>@@NumItems units</p>
<p>@@OrderValue dollars</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/baLn4ucj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make cells within a table align next to each other, they need to be in different "td" elements. If they are in the same "td" they will be part of a normal flow.

I demonstrated this for you here, by modifying your example.

```
<tr>
    <td> left </td>
    <td> right </td>
</tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DonatoBorrello/baLn4ucj/1/

Comment: so i cant have two different tables align next to each other? even if they are in the same row?

Comment: In my example, replace the text "left" with the html for one table, and the text "right" with the html of the other table. They will then align next to each other.

Comment: I see. Sorry, that was dumb. Thank you very much